# Examples and guidance for algorithms and procedures

Tags: disclosure, algorihm, examples, procedures

Where can I find examples and guidance on drafting an algorithm?
This is not for patenting the algorithm as such, which I believe must be attached to hardware.
This has more to do with the procedure to be followed for calibrating an apparatus.
If you claim this procedure in a separate claim how much detail must you give.
Say for instance the first two steps is really the uniqueness of the procedure, the rest is mere mathematical calculation, do you have to give details of the mathematical calculation?
The mathematical calculation is discussed in the body of the specification.
Is there a difference between an algorithm and procedure?

Answer (score 1):

> Say for instance the first two steps is really the uniqueness of the procedure, the rest is mere mathematical calculation, do you have to give details of the mathematical calculation?

This is a very tricky question. The main restriction to eliminating elements from a claim is that the claimed invention must still "work". In legal terms, it must fulfill the "utility" requirement. For example, claiming just one of a pair of pliers (i.e., one of the two hinged parts) may be problematic if the specification does not disclose a specific utility for it.

Many patents do "fudge" exact calcuations by using phrases like "calculating an adjustment parameter **based on** measurement A and measurement B". Notice that this recitation says nothing about the nature of the calculation but nevertheless ties measurements A and B to a useful result of obtaining the adjustment parameter. Since such a claim risks attack based on overbreadth (functional claiming), there should also be dependent claims that fill in specific ways of calculating.